# StencilJS - Bottomsheet does not work as expected. How to slide up the content?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, stenciljs

I am trying to make a Bottomsheet in Stencil. It shows up abruptly when I activate it. I want to show the overlay when the active property is set, and then slide up the content. Here is my component and its style:

Component:

```
import { Component, Prop, State, h, Listen } from '@stencil/core'

@Component({
    tag: 'my-bottomsheet',
    styleUrl: 'my-bottomsheet.scss',
    shadow: true
})

export class myBottomSheet {
    @State() active: boolean = false;

    toggle() {
        this.active = true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="my-bottomsheet">
                <button onClick={() => this.toggle()}>Show</button>
                { this.active &&
                    <div class="my-bottomsheet-overlay">
                        <div class="my-bottomsheet-content">
                            <span>This is the content!</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Style:

```
.my-bottomsheet-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

.my-bottomsheet-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: transform 0.5;
}
```

The overlay should show suddenly but the content should slide up. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Woah, noob mistake here! You can't play around with height: auto, you can however with max-height or height with a value. So here's the fix.

```
.my-bottomsheet-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

.my-bottomsheet-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    animation: riseUp 0.5s;
    max-height: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes riseUp{
    0% {
        max-height: 0;
    }

    100% {
        max-height: 300px;
    }
}
```

This is a perfectly working bottomsheet if anyone wants to use.